# biblatex adding "i,i" before author citation

Tags: biblatex, citing, inline

I've looked up and down through a bunch of forums and could not for the life of me find why my document might be printing "i,i" before the author both inline and in the bibliography for all citation entries (all papers and books referenced).

When I write:

```
\cite{Whipple2012}
```

I expect to get:

```
Whipple et al. 2012
```

But instead get:

```
i,i,Whipple et al. 2012
```

And in the biliography:

```
i,i,A A Whipple et al. ".....
```

I can't seem to figure this out. I have a whole bunch of packages, but I'll list them here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=25mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} % clears headers and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % removes the ruler bar
\cfoot{\thepage} % sets the page numbers to the center bottom of the page
\usepackage{titling} % allows me to use 'theauthor' in document
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.5em}%
}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % allows for use of landscape pages
\usepackage[english]{babel} % for language definition
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % for font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for font encoding
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings} % for making lists of things
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{graphicx} % to includegraphics figures
\usepackage{wrapfig} % for wrapping text around figures
\usepackage{grffile} % for other graphic filename extentions
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{underscore} % for literally underscores.
\usepackage{array} % for array and tabular formats (columns/rows/etc)
\usepackage{multirow} % for tables
\usepackage{adjustbox} % for rescaling graphic boxes
%\usepackage{pgf} % for creating graphics (tikz)
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xfrac} % for fancy fraction formatting
%\usepackage{textcomp} % allows for use of greek letters in document
\usepackage[
    citestyle=authoryear,
    backend=bibtex,
    sorting=ynt
    ]{biblatex} % Need for using biblio. Run in pdfLaTeX then in BibTex then back in pdfLaTex
```

This is for every citation entry in my .bib file, but here's the specific citation I'm talking about (as an example):

```
@article{Whipple2012,
    title = {{Sacramento-San Joaquin Delta Historical Ecology Investigation:  Exploring Pattern and Process.}},
   year = {2012},
    journal = {A Report of SFEI-ASC's Historical Ecology Program, Publication {\#}672},
    author = {Whipple, A A and Grossinger, R M and Rankin, D and Stanford, B and Askevold, R A and Program., Prepared for the California Department of Fish and Game and Ecosystem Restoration and {SFEI}},
    number = {august},
    pages = {408},
    url ={http://www.sfei.org/DeltaHEStudy%5Cnhttp://www.baydeltalive.com/assets/eec462358f80cc8d9910bfda974fa6f4/application/pdf/Delta_HistoricalEcologyStudy_SFEI_ASC_2012_lowres_0.pdf},
    isbn = {SFEI-AEC's Historical Ecology Program, Publication {\#}672},
    keywords = {Historic, SFE, local}
}
```

Comment: you have not shown the main source of the problem text, the bibtex entry for that publication

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry about that! I wasn't very clear. I edited the post so it might make more sense now.

Comment: You example does not reproduce your problem. Please add `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. So that it compiles and shows your issue. Remove any packages that are irrelevant. Also, look over your bib record. Many of the fields seem wrong (include the `url`). This seems like a report rather than a journal. I'd use a different entry type. And finally, `biber` is recommended of `bibtex` for `biblatex` now.

Comment: Mhhh, this looks as though the name format is messed up. Do you also get errors or warnings in the `.log` and `.blg` files? Do you have any `biblatex` modifications you have not shown us in your preamble? Anyway, in order to diagnose this further we need to see an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that would be code we can run without modification that reproduces the issue. I have a hunch that you are using an outdated version of `biblatex` which clashes with `\usepackage{underscore}`.

Comment: Are you sure about the last “author”?

Comment: @egreg - nice catch, but unfortunately as I said this isn't an issue with this particular citation. It's every citation.

Comment: @moewe - It was the underscore package! I thought I was commenting it out, but there were two imports!

All - sorry for the sloppy request w/o a MWE. I'll do better next time!

Answer (score 2):

You are using an outdated version of `biblatex`. In that version `biblatex` used `_i` to indicate the initials of a name. That underscore causes problems when the `underscore` package is loaded because then the character, which is special anyway, behaves differently. This caused problems with other packages as well, IIRC, so `biblatex` dropped the `_` in later versions.

The solution is

- to update `biblatex` (and Biber) to their current version 3.10 (and 2.10), and
- to drop the `underscore` package if you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this is on the Overleaf.com platform so I may have to request a biblatex update!